# Error while trying to open a new window with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm creating an electron with JavaScript but when I try to create a new window it gives me the error at the bottom of the page (click the link). I don't know what to do cause I cannot find the error.

```
function createAddWindow() {
  addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Administrator Panel'
  });
  addWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, "addWindow.html"),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));
}

const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
});

const mainMenuTemplate = [
  {
    label: 'File',
    submenu:  [
      {
        label: 'Administrator Panel',
        click() {
          createAddWindow();
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'Exit',
        accelerator: process.platform == 'darwin' ? 'Command + Q' : 'Ctrl + Q',
        click() {
          app.quit();
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

[image: Error]

https://hastebin.com/amepavehux.js

Can someone help with out with that?

Comment: Can you put the full code on pastebin so I can see it all?

Comment: @steve Yes, one minute

Comment: @steve Question updated

Comment: I'll be back in a moment with the solution

Comment: Hope that helps. I tested and it works

Comment: @steve, thanks for doing this, but I also find the error and fixed it without doing what you did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your problem is your function is out of the global scope. You can: A.) Create a global function or B.) Remove the unnecessary function and do something such as this:

```js
const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
});

const mainMenuTemplate = [
  {
    label: 'File',
    submenu:  [
      {
        label: 'Administrator Panel',
        click() {
            addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                title: 'Administrator Panel'
              });
              addWindow.loadURL(url.format({
                pathname: path.join(__dirname, "addWindow.html"),
                protocol: 'file:',
                slashes: true
              }));
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'Exit',
        accelerator: process.platform == 'darwin' ? 'Command + Q' : 'Ctrl + Q',
        click() {
          app.quit();
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I simply removed the function and put its code inside of the `click` handler.

If you are determined to use the function, read up on global variables here: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote

Comment: Thanks for doing this, but I also find the error and fixed it without doing what you did.